# Correct way to get underset alignement

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, alignment, overset

I am currently trying to get this kind of alignement :

[image]

By using the `aligned-overset` package, i have managed to come up with :

This is tedious and not very good :

```
%%%%%%%%%%% préambule %%%%%%%%%%%
% chercher les packages https://www.ctan.org/search?phrase=%
%
%% pour le document %%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}% pour gérer les dimensions
\usepackage[french]{babel}% rajouter éventuellement english, greek, etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% gestion des accents (pour les pdf)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% encodage du fichier source
\usepackage{xcolor}% pour gérer les couleurs
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour gérer les entêtes et bas de pages
%
%% pour les maths %%
\usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{stmaryrd} \usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage{nccmath} \usepackage{mathtools}%
\usepackage{amsthm}% pour théorèmes, preuves...
\usepackage{esint}% pour les intégrales
\usepackage{aligned-overset}% pour les alignements
%
%% pour améliorer les rapports
\usepackage{graphicx,pdfpages}% pour inclure des images ou des pdf
\usepackage{array,enumitem}% pour optimiser des modes
%
%
%
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \color{red}
    \item {\sl Calculons} \(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\).
      \begin{align*}
        \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k
        \underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{Binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}&
          =\sum_{k=\boxed{0}}^{\boxed{n}}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k - \binom{n}{0}(-1)^0 - \binom{n}{n}(-1)^n,\\
        \underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{Binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}&=
          \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k -1 - (-1)^n,\\
        \underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{Binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}&=
          \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k1^{n-k} -1 + (-1)^{n+1},\\
        \underset{\substack{\text{binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}&=
          (-1+1)^{n} - 1 + (-1)^{n+1},\\
        \underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{Binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}&=
          \boxed{-1+(-1)^{n+1}}.
      \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which gives, [image]

I can't figure out how to make the text inside the boxes smaller, and also my way of aligning using `phantom` is very tedious and error prone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am like a snail but I add my idea anyway I have:

1. deleted `amsmath` that is a subset of `mathtools`;
2. deleted `\usepackage{aligned-overset}` using an array with the option `rcll`;
3. used the font and mathfont of the 1st image `\usepackage{newtxtext} \usepackage{mathptmx}`;
4. increased the vertical spaces with `[1.5em]` and  `[2em]`;
5. used a `\mkern-5mu` (for the first line) to have the perfect alignment and `\displaystyle` always because  I had a `\sum` always inline mode;
6. used `\scriptstyle` command to have a tiny `0` and `n` into the boxes (same size of the others limits of the sum);
7. used `\textsl{Calculons}` instead of the old command `\sl`.

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
   \usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}% pour gérer les dimensions
   \usepackage[french]{babel}% rajouter éventuellement english, greek, etc.
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% gestion des accents (pour les pdf)
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% encodage du fichier source
   \usepackage{xcolor}% pour gérer les couleurs
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour gérer les entêtes et bas de pages
   %
   %% pour les maths %%
   \usepackage{amssymb}%
   \usepackage{stmaryrd} \usepackage{mathrsfs}%
   \usepackage{nccmath} \usepackage{mathtools}%
   \usepackage{amsthm}% pour théorèmes, preuves...
   \usepackage{esint}% pour les intégrales
   \usepackage{newtxtext}
   \usepackage{mathptmx}

   %
   %% pour améliorer les rapports
   \usepackage{graphicx,pdfpages}% pour inclure des images ou des pdf
   \usepackage{array,enumitem}% pour optimiser des modes
   \begin{document}
     \begin{enumerate}
       \color{red}
       \item \textsl{Calculons} $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k$.
         \[\begin{array}{rcll}
           \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k
           & = &\mkern-5mu\displaystyle \sum_{k=\boxed{\scriptstyle 0}}^{\boxed{\scriptstyle n}}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k-\binom{n}{0}(-1)^0 - \binom{n}{n}(-1)^n,\\[1.5em]
           & = &\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k-1-(-1)^n,\\[1.5em]
           & = &\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k 1^{n-k} -1 + (-1)^{n+1},\\[1.5em]
           & \underset{\substack{\text{Binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}{=} &(-1+1)^{n} - 1 + (-1)^{n+1},\\[2em]
           & = &\boxed{-1+(-1)^{n+1}}.
         \end{array}
         \]
     \end{enumerate}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your usage of `\underset` is wrong: it should be `\underset{...}{=}` with the `&` preceding it.

I also provide a redefinition of `\boxed` which, in the original definition, always use `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\boxed}[1]{\mathpalette\boxed@{#1}}
\newcommand{\boxed@}[2]{%
  \fbox{$\m@th#1#2\mathstrut$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k
  &\underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}{=}
   \sum_{k=\boxed{0}}^{\boxed{n}}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k - \binom{n}{0}(-1)^0 - \binom{n}{n}(-1)^n,
\\
  &\underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}{=}
   \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k -1 - (-1)^n,
\\
  &\underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}{=}
   \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k1^{n-k} -1 + (-1)^{n+1},
\\
  &\underset{\substack{\text{binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}{=}
  (-1+1)^{n} - 1 + (-1)^{n+1},
\\
  &\underset{\phantom{\substack{\text{binôme de} \\ \text{Newton}}}}{=}
   \boxed{-1+(-1)^{n+1}}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd omit the punctuation at the end of lines, except the last. And I'd also avoid the spaced equals signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sboxed}[1]{{\mathpalette\sboxed@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sboxed@}[2]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
  \fbox{$\m@th#1#2\mathstrut$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k
  &=\sum_{k=\sboxed{0}}^{\sboxed{n}}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k - \binom{n}{0}(-1)^0 - \binom{n}{n}(-1)^n
\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k -1 - (-1)^n
\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k1^{n-k} -1 + (-1)^{n+1}
\\
  &=(-1+1)^{n} - 1 + (-1)^{n+1} \qquad\text{(binôme de Newton)}
\\
  &=\sboxed{-1+(-1)^{n+1}}\,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Here, rather than redefining `\boxed`, I used a different command, which maybe is better also for the preceding solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with`eqparbox` and `stackengine`.

Some remarks: nowadays, you don't have to load `inputenc` with option `[utf8]` since it is what LaTeX expects by default. Also, needless to load `amsmath` if you load  `mathtools`, which does it for you.

I took the liberty to replace the vivid red with another red.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}% pour gérer les dimensions
\usepackage[french]{babel}% rajouter éventuellement english, greek, etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% gestion des accents (pour les pdf)
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}% pour gérer les couleurs
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour gérer les entêtes et bas de pages
%
%% pour les maths %%
\usepackage{amssymb} %
\usepackage{stmaryrd} \usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage{nccmath} \usepackage{mathtools}%
\usepackage{amsthm}% pour théorèmes, preuves...
\usepackage{esint}% pour les intégrales
\usepackage{aligned-overset}% pour les alignements
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} %
%% pour améliorer les rapports
\usepackage{graphicx,pdfpages}% pour inclure des images ou des pdf
\usepackage{array,enumitem}% pour optimiser des modes
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][E]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

%
\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \color{IndianRed}
    \item {\sl Calculons} \(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\).
      \begin{align*}
        \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k
        & \eqmathbox{=}\sum_{k=\boxed{\scriptstyle 0}}^{\boxed{\scriptstyle n}}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k - \binom{n}{0}(-1)^0 - \binom{n}{n}(-1)^n,\\
        &\eqmathbox{=} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k -1 - (-1)^n,\\
        &\eqmathbox{=} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k1^{n-k} -1 + (-1)^{n+1},\\
         & \eqmathbox{\underset{\;\scriptsize\Centerstack{binôme de\\ Newton }\;}{=}} (-1+1)^{n} - 1 + (-1)^{n+1},\\
        &\eqmathbox{=} \boxed{-1+(-1)^{n+1}}.
      \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}

  \end{document}
```

[image]